# Several variables called at once javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

This is a time saver question and - in more practical reasons - a code saver question. I was looking at my long list of variables all meant to `document.getElementById("x");` of 24 different IDs. I have to `xVar.removeAttribute("y");` for each one but the one the viewer is clicking. Is it possible to make a variable that calls other variables such as `var year = june, july, etc. //minus the etc. part obviously` and then call it as `year.removeAttribute("y");`?

Or do I have to constantly rewrite `w.removeAttribute("y"); v.removeAttribute("y");`etc.

Any advice? Time savers? Help at all would be appreciated :)

---------- UPDATE ------------

To clarify:

How do I turn

```
    var jan = document.getElementById("january");
var feb = document.getElementById("february");
var mar = document.getElementById("march");
var apr = document.getElementById("april");
var may = document.getElementById("may");
var jun = document.getElementById("june");
var jul = document.getElementById("july");
var aug = document.getElementById("august");
var sep = document.getElementById("september");
var oct = document.getElementById("october");
var nov = document.getElementById("november");
var dec = document.getElementById("december");
```

into something like

```
var year = //all of the above
```

??

Comment: No need to downvote until the question is finished.

Comment: Read up on arrays and for loops.

Comment: Add the items you wish to modify to an array, then loop through the array and call the method.  You wouldn't have to constantly rewrite anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use an array for those variables.